# Achieve smooth iFrame navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, postmessage

I have an iFrame with navigation inside of it, meaning the iframe src will be changed when navigating inside it. The navigation code inside the iFrame is something like:

```
window.location = "new URL";
```

While this is working the user experience is really bad, especially on mobile devices (I can see a "blink" / "flash" when iFrame changes his source)

I tried to implement something similar to what Chris Coyier had [here](http://css-tricks.com/prevent-white-flash-iframe/), by triggering a postMessage to the parent while navigating, telling the parent to hide/show the iFrame while src is being changed. Something like (this is inside parent postMessage event):

```
var $iFrame = $('iframe');

$iFrame.css({'visibility': 'hidden'});

$iFrame.load(function(){
    $iFrame.css({'visibility': 'visible'});
});
```

This will work, but the result is not better - I can still see this "blink" when the iFrame is being hidden-visible by my new code.

My 3rd try included having a new iFrame and give it the new source, only when it loaded making it visible and hiding the first one. This did not improve the results as well:

```
 var $iFrame = $('.iFrame1');
 var $iFrame2 = $('.iFrame2');

 $iFrame2.attr('src', encodeURIComponent(url));

 $iFrame2.load(function(){
     $iFrame2.css({'visibility': 'visible'});
     $iFrame.css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
 });
```

Any help getting a smoother transition (on mobile devices!) will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood your problem correct, you could try to change the opacity, and not the visibility. With this change you would be able to give it a short Fade-Transition. This could be achieved with CSS or jQuery, whatever you prefer.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong by using the term "transition". What I want to achieve is navigation without screen "blink", similar to what you will get when navigating a regular page, without an iFrame.